# Duplicar planilha

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, automatização, planilha

Ola,tenho uma planilha que contem alguns dados importantes, gostaria de saber se existe alguma de duplicar esse planilha automaticamente, de forma que eu manipule os dados em uma planilha e quando clique em salvar ela ja salve um backup dela, sem que eu precise fazer as mudancas manualmente...

Answer (score 1):

Na árvore de projeto de dois cliques em **EstaPastaDeTrabalho**. Em seguida, na parte superior na *comboBox* da esquerda selecione **Workbook**, é de se esperar que automaticamente apareça isso:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

Caso não apareça isso basta selecione no *comboBox* da direita a função *Open*. E acrescente a função como descrito a seguir.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    planilha_backup
End Sub
```

**Crie um novo módulo e insira está função**

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Function planilha_backup()
    Dim str_nome_da_pasta_de_trabalho As String
    Dim str_caminho_da_pasta_de_trabalho As String
    Dim str_data_hora As String
    Dim diretorio As String
    str_data_hora = Replace(Date, "/", "-") & "_" & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now) & Second(Now) & "_"
    str_nome_da_pasta_de_trabalho = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    str_caminho_da_pasta_de_trabalho = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    diretorio = str_caminho_da_pasta_de_trabalho & "\" & "bkp_" & str_data_hora & str_nome_da_pasta_de_trabalho

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        diretorio, FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

    str_nome_da_pasta_de_trabalho = ""
    str_caminho_da_pasta_de_trabalho = ""
    str_data_hora = ""
    diretorio = ""
End Function
```